# Unbind and bind the handler using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to unbind and bind the handler on clone element because it has the old parameter in the function. I has look for the web https://www.andismith.com/blogs/2011/11/on-and-off/and tried but it didn't work. Would someone tell me how to solve my issue. Thanks in advance.

There is my code:

```
var index = totalDropbox.length;  
var firstRow = panel.find('tr:nth-child(1)');
var fristClone = firstRow.clone( );      
         
 //update the id
var dropID = ' drp_' + index.toString();
var drop = fristClone.find('td:eq(1)').find('select');
drop.attr('id', dropID);
drop.attr('name', dropID);
drop.off('onchange');
drop.on('onchange', 'drop_change(\'' + dropID +'\')' );
```

The clone function is onchange="drop_change('drp_0') and I need to change to be onchange="drop_change('drp_1')

Answer (score 0):

I think you've got a bit of confusion going on here as it looks like you've got an inline handler attached to your DOM as per the last sentence.

To remove an inline handler, you'd need to use `removeAttr` method like so:

`drop.removeAttr("onchange");`

You're then attaching an event handler to the selected element, to unbind that one you'd need to use `off` like as per above.